# Accessing ENV var in different files in Node.js using dotenv

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I have a simple app I'm working on that uses the Google Maps API, and Darksky API; I've installed dotenv to handle hiding the keys for both. After following the Docs I was able to make this work but only in the file where dotenv in being required (app.js). I need access to the ENV variables in my footer.ejs file, and a weather.js file but process.env is not defined in them. Do I have to export dotenv? How do this? Thanks, in advance.

### app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
Dotenv = require('dotenv').config(),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

// HomePage
app.get('/',function(req, res){
  res.render('home');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || process.env.LOC_PORT,function(err){
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('Server Running: '+ process.env.LOC_PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `env.js` file, that export you environment variables as follow:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

module.exports = {
  getEnvVariables: function () {
    const vars = dotenv.load();
    const jsonVars = {};
    for (const key in vars) jsonVars[key] = JSON.stringify(vars[key]);
    return jsonVars;
  },
};
```

Then just `import {getEnvVariables} from './env';` after that.

In case you're using **Webpack**, you may add the following plugin to your weback configuration file so you dont't need to put the import line in any file across your app anyomore:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': env.getEnvVariables()
}),
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I'm getting an, 'Unexpected token import' error from weather.js, and a 'require is not defined' error from env.js.

Comment: @halfacreyum Sorry, this is ES6 syntax, you can just use `require` as well and replace `const`s in my answer with `var`s.

Comment: Sorry, I did switch const's to var's I should of mentioned that. I'm still getting the error from the env.js file ('require is not defined'), I'm loading the script for that file in the footer.